# Renderizando um objeto JSON com a junção de modelos diferentes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

Estou desenvolvendo uma API com rails 5 e tenho os seguintes models:

```
class cotacao < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :usuario
  has_many :cotacao_itens, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cotacao_itens, allow_destroy: true
end

class CotacaoItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cotacao
end

class Peca < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :fornecedor
end

class Fornecedor < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :usuario
  has_many :pecas
end
```

Agora preciso criar um método que a partir de uma cotacao, sejam apresentadas todas as peças agrupadas por forcenecedor, e renderizado um objeto JSON com a seguinte estrutura:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "fornecedor 1",
        "pecas": [
            {"numero": "1999"},
            {"numero": "2555"}]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "fornecedor 2",
        "pecas": [
            {"numero": "1999"},
            {"numero": "2555"},
            {"numero": "3666"}]
    }
]
```

Até o momento esse método (incompleto) está da seguinte forma:

```
def quotation_suppliers
    quotation = Quotation.find(params[:id])

    parts = []
    suppliers = []

    quotation.quotation_items.each do |item|
      parts << Part.select { |part| part.part_number == item.part_number }
    end

    render json: parts, status: 200
  end
```

Estou utilizando o ActiveModel Serializer para formatar a saída do JSON, mas a minha dificuldade está sendo justamente na criação do método "quotation_suppliers" e a lógica necessária para criar esse resultado.

**EDIT**

Consegui chegar bem próximo do resultado que estou buscando criando o seguinte método em models/quotation.rb

```
def parts
    part_numbers = self.quotation_items.map { |item| item.part_number }
    parts = part_numbers.map { |item| Part.where(part_number: item) }
    parts = parts.flatten.group_by(&:supplier_id)
end
```

Esse método imprime um hash agrupado pelo ID do supplier, porém preciso apresentar outro atributo, no lugar do ID seria o social_name. Então adicionei o seguinte código:

```
suppliers = parts.keys.map { |k| parts[Supplier.find(k).social_name] = parts.delete(k) }
```

Dessa forma consigo ver o resultado que preciso no console, porém no postman o hash fica sem o social_name. Acredito que isso esteja relacionado a configuração do quotation_serializer:

```
class Api::V2::QuotationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :parts
end
```

Mas ainda não sei o que preciso fazer pra apresentar também o attributo social_name no hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver! Cheguei no resultado que precisava com o seguinte método:

```
def parts
    part_numbers = self.quotation_items.map { |item| item.part_number }
    parts = part_numbers.map { |item| Part.where(part_number: item) }
    parts = parts.flatten.group_by(&:supplier_id)
    parts.keys.map { |k| parts[Supplier.find(k).social_name] = parts.delete(k) }
    parts
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

O ActiveModel::Serializer permite que você tenha múltiplos serializadores para o mesmo modelo.

```
class SimplePartSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name
end

class ComplexPartSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  has_many :suppliers
  attributes :id, :name, :model_id, :created_at, :updated_at
end
```

Para utilizar, você só precisar especificar qual serializador você quer utilizar, dessa forma:

```
# para múltiplas instâncias de part (no caso de um array)
render json: parts, status: 200, each_serializer: ComplexPartSerializer

# para uma só instância de part (no caso um objeto único)
render json: @people, serializer: ComplexPartSerializer
```

Comment: Interessante a sua dica vnbrs, mas a minha dúvida está em como criar a lógica do método "quotation_suppliers" de forma que ele traga as informações que preciso.